# Find the height of the parallelepiped constructed by vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is the last question of my homework, in class we only learned about finding the volume of the parallelepiped using the triple scalar product. But I have no idea how the height can be found. Is the height just the magnitude of $\vec{c}$?

The question: Find the height of the parallelopiped constructed by the vectors
$\vec{a} = (1, -1, 1)$, $\vec{b} = (-2, 1, 2)$ and $\vec{c} = (3, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the volume also from:
$height * S = volume$

Where $S$ is the surface area of the base face

So by using:
$\frac{volume}{S}=height $
You can find the height.

You can find $S$ by finding the base surface area which is created by $|\vec{v}$ X $\vec{u}|$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.